# Cordova / Phonegap device to device file transfer

Tags: android, ios, cordova, bluetooth

How do I transfer data from one device to another with Cordova/Phonegap?  Most likely, I would prefer to transfer a file, though transferring a string data would work as well.  I need to support Android, IOS, Windows Phone 8.x and Windows 8.x platforms.

I was thinking I could use a bluetooth plugin, but I do not see any bluetooth plugins that support all of the platforms I require.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to implement this plugin on your app

https://github.com/randdusing/BluetoothLE